# Failing to iterate over AdComputer names to get description

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, active-directory

I am using ActiveDirectory and Powershell to get the description of computers in the AD Group
However, when I try to get batch output, I get InvalidArgument error in powershell

When I use a single line:
`Get-AdComputer -Filter * -Identity **COMPUTERNAME **-Properties * | Select-Object name, description`

I get the correct response:

```
Name               Description                                                                                
----              -----------                                                                                
COMPUTERNAME      Computer description
```

However, when I use the this code to get a batch of results:

```
$UL = Get-ADGroupMember -identity "Groupname"| Select-Object name
Foreach ($i in $UL.Name)
{
    $i.ToString()
    Write-Host $i.GetType()
    Get-AdComputer -Filter * -Identity "$i" -Properties * | Select-Object name, description
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Get-ADComputer : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At C:\apps\ActiveDirectory_UserList.ps1:6 char:1
+ Get-AdComputer -Filter * -Identity "$i" -Properties * | Select-Object ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

Comment: You're attempting to use 2 different parameter sets in one calling. Use either `-Identity`, or `-Filter` by themselves and not combined.

Comment: Also, `Get-ADGroupMember` can return objects of type `user`, `group` and `computer`. You should only use `Get-ADComputer` on objects with `.objectClass` equal to 'computer'. PLUS do **not** use `-Properties *` if the only extra property you need is 'description'

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? Please have a look at the [tour] where you can see how to mark a question 'done' so other users can benefit as well

Answer (score 0):

As commented by [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74584801/failing-to-iterate-over-adcomputer-names-to-get-description#comment131653987_74584801), you cannot use both `-Filter` and `-Identity` together as these parameter sets rule eachother out giving you the error message

> Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

Next, [Get-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroupmember) will not just return computer objects,
but also users and other groups can be members of one particular group.
Therefore, if you want to get output for computer objects only, you will need to filter out the other object types.

Luckily, each group member has a property called `objectClass`. This is a string containing either 'user', 'computer'  or 'group',
so it is realy quite easy to check on that:

```
# get all members of the group, filter with a Where-Object clause to receive only computer objects
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Groupname" | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'computer'}
foreach ($computer in $members) {
    $computer | Get-ADComputer -Properties Description | Select-Object Name, Description
}
```

<sup>By default, `Get-ADComputer` returns objects with these properties:
`DistinguishedName, DNSHostName, Enabled, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID,  UserPrincipalName`, so in this case you only have to ask for the extra property `Description`</sup>